# How to get the size of a type in C++?

Tags: c++, clang, oclint

I am looking for a C++ function that returns the size of a type. For example :

```
#include <stdint.h> 

int16_t my_var; 
int32_t size_of_var; 

// magical_function is what I'm looking for
// size_of_var should be equal to 16 because my_var is a int16_t
size_of_var = my_var.magical_function() ;
```

I know that size() exists to get the length of a string, so I guess there is a function indicating that too.

Moreover, I'm working with Clang library, so I can get a Type (http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Type.html) but I currently have no idea to compare 2 types and to know the bigger between those two.

Comment: You could use sizeof() this way `size_of_var = sizeof(my_var);`

Comment: _'size_of_var should be equal to 16 because my_var is a int16_t'_ size of types is counted in bytes, not bits actually.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In case you want 16 instead of 2 for `int16_t`

```
sizeof(my_var) * CHAR_BIT
```

`sizeof` give you how many bytes, and `CHAR_BIT` give you how many bits in a byte (normally 8)

Comment: I'd add, that `sizeof(char) == 1`, and the `sizeof(MY_TYPE)` is given in multiples of `sizeof(char)`. What is a bit confusing, that `byte` for most people means 8 bits, while it's actually supposed to mean the "number of bits used to encode a single character of text". Source of knowledge: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte

Comment: @Zsolt You say it's a bit confusing, but sometimes it can be two bits confusing.

Comment: @Podlie: I just don't understand what you wanted to say.

Comment: @Zsolt Historically.

Answer (score 7):

Available syntaxes for the command (sizeof) are:

- sizeof( type )
- sizeof expression

Both of them return `std::size_t`.

Examples of types are `int`, `float`, `double`, whereas expressions can evaluate the size of an object. For clarification purposes I'll add the following:

```
sizeof(int);     // Return size of int type.
sizeof(float);   // Return size of float type.
sizeof(double);  // Return size of double type.

struct my_struct {};  // Creates an empty struct named my_struct.
my_struct alpha;      // Initializes alpha as a my_struct.
sizeof alpha;         // Returns size of alpha.
```

Further information can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

You may try like this:

```
size_of_var = sizeof(my_var);
```

In your case you may try with:

```
sizeof(my_var) * CHAR_BIT
```

**On a side note:**

C99 standard requires that

```
sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) < sizeof(long long)

Type           C99 Minimum     Windows 32bit
char           8               8
short          16              16
int            16              32
long           32              32
long long      64              64
```

Also `int8_t` is guaranteed to be **8 bits**, and `int16_t` is guaranteed to be **16 bits**, etc.

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the size of a type in bits, use the `CHAR_BIT` macro in conjunction with the `sizeof` operator:

```
#include <cstdint> 
#include <climits>

int16_t my_var; 
int32_t size_of_var; 

// size_of_var should be equal to 16 because my_var is a int16_t
size_of_var = CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int16_t);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use sizeof operator.

```
size_of_var = sizeof(my_var);
```

Answer (score 1):

Th unary operator `sizeof()` will return you the size of your variable in bytes.

Use it like this:

```
size_of_var = sizeof(my_var);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `sizeof` operator will give you the number of bytes, but you ask for the number of bits. All mass consumer computers have eight bits per byte, so your function can be defined as:

```
template<typename T>
int bitsize(const T& var) {
    return sizeof(var) * 8;
}
```

There are, however, some some very specific machines that don't have eight bits per byte. In that case you can use the `CHAR_BIT` macro:

```
#include <climits>

template<typename T>
int bitsize(const T& var) {
    return sizeof(var) * CHAR_BIT;
}
```

It might be worth noting that in this case it's better to have a macro that gives you the number of bits and not a function. A macro will always give you a compile-time constant:

```
#include <climits>
#define BITSIZE(VAR) (sizeof(VAR) * CHAR_BIT)
```